# JavaFx: How to make a cube adjust to window resize

Tags: java, oop, javafx, drawing, shapes

I'm having problems with a javafx exercise I'm doing. Basically the problem states to make a rectangular cube and make it so that it automatically expands or contracts as you adjust the window size. I'm done with the first part of the part of the program but having difficulty with the second. Here's my code:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane pane = new Pane();

    //Draw two rectangles
    Rectangle upper = new Rectangle(140, 100, 120, 100);
    upper.setFill(null);
    upper.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    Rectangle lower = new Rectangle(100, 140, 120, 100);
    lower.setFill(null);
    lower.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    //Draw the line connecting them
    Line ul = new Line(140, 100, 100, 140);
    Line ur = new Line(260, 100, 220, 140);
    Line ll = new Line(140, 200, 100, 240);
    Line lr = new Line(260, 200, 220, 240);

    pane.getChildren().addAll(upper, lower, ul, ur, ll, lr);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 200, 200);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise14");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

The rectangular cube appears as thus, but I can't figure out how to make it expand or contract when I resize the window:

[image: cube is drawn]

[image: cube does not resize properly]

I'm thinking I need to bind each individual shape to the pane or something, but I'm not sure where to begin. Would appreciate a point in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add change listeners to the scene and calculate the dimensions of the cube relative to the width and height of the scene. Something like this:

```
ChangeListener<Number> listenerX = new ChangeListener<Number>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {

        System.out.println( "X: observable: " + observable + ", oldValue: " + oldValue.doubleValue() + ", newValue: " + newValue.doubleValue());

        // TODO:
        // Lines:
        //   line.setStartX(...)
        //   line.setStartY(...)
        //   line.setEndX(...)
        //   line.setEndY(...)
        // 
        // Rectangles:
        //   rect.setTranslateX(...)
        //   rect.setTranslateY(...)
        //   rect.setWidth(...)
        //   rect.setHeight(...)
        // hint: instead of translate you can use rect.relocate(..., ...). translate is relative, relocate applies layoutX/Y and translateX/Y

    }
};

ChangeListener<Number> listenerY = new ChangeListener<Number>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {

        System.out.println( "Y: observable: " + observable + ", oldValue: " + oldValue.doubleValue() + ", newValue: " + newValue.doubleValue());

        // similare to listenerX

    }
};

scene.widthProperty().addListener( listenerX);
scene.heightProperty().addListener( listenerY);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the approach explained over here: http://fxexperience.com/2014/05/resizable-grid-using-canvas/

Basically you create your custom Pane and override the 'layoutChildren()' method to draw your cube. You "just" have to replace the drawing code with your cube.

This is much faster than using the listener approach: When the node is resized it will draw twice at a minimum when using listeners (when width and height are set). 'layoutChildren()' will at most do one draw per frame.